# Something is puzzling me about the use of ftp.nlst on a windows ftp server

Tags: ruby, ftp

So I was reading the documentation for the method `nlst` in the NET::FTP module (ruby-1.8.6). The source code displayed is

```
# File net/ftp.rb, line 602
def nlst(dir = nil)
  cmd = "NLST"
  if dir
    cmd = cmd + " " + dir
  end
  files = []
  retrlines(cmd) do |line|
    files.push(line)
  end
  return files
end
```

So the command is written literally in the string `cmd`, executed via `retrlines` and the list of files is given back right?

The thing I don't understand is that on my windows ftp server there is no such command:

```
230 User logged in.
Remote system type is Windows_NT.
ftp> nlst
?Invalid command
ftp>
```

and yet the the method returns the file list. How is it possible? The source code doesn't appear to have an abstraction of some sort on the command and also the source code of retrlines doesn't have anything special (to me).

```
# File lib/net/ftp.rb, line 475
    def retrlines(cmd) # :yield: line
      synchronize do
        with_binary(false) do
          conn = transfercmd(cmd)
          loop do
            line = conn.gets
            break if line == nil
            yield(line.sub(/\r?\n\z/, ""), !line.match(/\n\z/).nil?)
          end
          conn.close
          voidresp
        end
      end
    end
```

I traced back the methods called to `sendcmd` inside `transfercmd` but I have no clue really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is who is telling you `?Invalid command`?

In this case it's the FTP **client**, not the server.

The client is just a front-end for commands that it implements, converting these front-end commands into proper FTP protocol command strings for the server.

What you're looking for is the `nlist` (not `nlst`) command in your client, which will issue the `NLST` FTP protocol command to the server.

```
ftp> help nlst
?Invalid help command nlst
ftp> help nlist
nlist           nlist contents of remote directory
ftp>
```